# How to add a button in navbar to show/hide a sidebar in shiny like in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I want to add a [burger menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ85Q.png) in the navbar to toggle a sidebar in a shiny app.

Comment: Please provide a minimal shiny app and show what you've already tried

Comment: i put a image, 
so i means that i want to add a "button bars" ( a three bars icon) or any button or icon, to hide or to show a sidebar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might get you started:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.toggleSidebarPanel % 2 == 0", sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                  label = "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    )),
    mainPanel(actionButton("toggleSidebarPanel", "", icon = icon("bars")),
              plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: @kraggle please ask a new question including a reproducible example and link it here. Cheers

Comment: @kraggle yes, I do know `bslib`. As already mentioned above if you have a new question create a new post as `bslib` has no direct relation to the above original question.